# PHP Root Directory Listing

Tags: php

There is any ways to listing all main directories present in php server(may it is wamp or xampp).

Comment: Could you clarify this question, please? I'm not sure what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what you mean by "root directory" it could be as simple as

```
foreach( glob($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $fn) {
  echo basename($fn), "<br />\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `glob()` function mentioned is interesting, check it out [here](http://www.php.net/glob)

If you use it without specifying the path and only givin a file extension, for instance "*.php" it will search within the current directory.